# Mean, max and min of a measure in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a database, which you can see in the image "BDD" whose most important columns are:

- Program: Indicates the date of the program (when the ship service date was defined).
- Date: The date of attention of the BT (This can change between programs).
- Ship: The name of the ship.
- Owner of the shipment.

What I did was create a new table "Measures" where I create 3 measures:

1. First program: It helps me find the service date (Date column) associated with the first program (Program column) of each vessel.
2. Last program: It helps me find the service date associated with the last program of each ship.
3. Day diff: using the DAYDIFF function between first program and last program.

Thus I obtained the matrix that can be seen in the attached photograph (which is filtered by owner = my company).
[image]
Now I would like to calculate the daydiff average, but I can't do it. I can't use AVERAGE because daydiff is not a column, but a measure, I've tried with more functions (average, averagex, meanx, etc) and nothing works for me.

On the other hand, when trying to calculate the maximum difference I have not been successful either (I used the maxx function), it also failed for the minimum.

Update:
Code of Last program

```
CALCULATE(
    MAX(BDD[Date]), 
        ALLEXCEPT(BDD,BDD[Ship]),
            BDD[Program] = MAX(BDD[Program]))
```

Code of First program

```
CALCULATE(
    MIN(BDD[Date]), 
        ALLEXCEPT(BDD,BDD[Ship]),
            BDD[Program] = MIN(BDD[Program]))
```

Code of Day Dif

```
DATEDIFF([First program], [Last program], DAY)
```

What i've tried to calculate the mean is:

```
Mean day diff = calculate(GEOMEANX(Medidas,Medidas[Day dif]),FILTER(BDD,BDD[Owner]="Company"))
```

This doesn't work, it should be 4.19 days and the result given is 51.
Then i tried using `AVERAGE` but i can't because "day dif" is not a column, but i was able to use `AVERAGEX(Medidas, Medidas[Day dif])`, also didn't work.

When i tried calculating the SUM of Day dif with `SUMX(Medidas, Medidas[Day dif])`= 51. But it should be 88.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, and explain why you thing it did not work. A data sample to reproduce your problem would be great too.

Comment: @RADO i edited the question! Which is the best way to add data for you?